# Trying to extract count of occurrences of word "temperature" only in fields of JSON document by using Groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am actually new to groovy and I am trying to read the json document file and count the occurrences of specific word "temperature" in the fields of json document. The word should match exactly. like "high_temperature should not be equal to "temperature". Only "temperature" should be equal to "temperature".

```
def file = new File('src/main/resources/climate_change_tweets_all.json')
file.each{
if (it.contains(" temperature ")){
        temperature++
    }
}
```

Comment: What relevance has the JSON format here?  Do you want to count the occurences of the word "temperature" in an JSON agnostic way or do you want to count it in say in string values and keys of said JSON?

Comment: Its in a JSON format. For example:- In my JSON file, I have a field “full_text” for each row.. I want to check the string value of that field and find an occurrence of word “temperature” in that string.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the format you could simply

```
def file = new File('src/main/resources/climate_change_tweets_all.json')
int count = file.text.count ' temperature '
```

If you need to respect case-sensitivity or word position, you would have to use regexp:

```
int count = 0
file.text.eachMatch( /\btemperature\b/ ){ count++ }
```